# Different time zones in all_scheduler_job_run_details columns

Tags: oracle, scheduled-tasks

I'm currently looking into an issue where an hour time mismatch is reported in a job log report. Querying the all_scheduler_job_run_details for a particular job I get the following results:

```
select log_date
      ,actual_start_date
  from all_scheduler_job_run_details
 where ...

log_date = 03-JAN-19 02.45.11.116000 PM +01:00
actual_start_date = 03-JAN-19 03.45.11.116000 PM +02:00
```

Note that log_date is with timezone + 1 and actual_start_date is with time_zone + 2.

What would cause these times to be stored with different time_zones in the job_run_detail log?

Comment: Please provide values for `DBMS_SCHEDULER.GET_SCHEDULER_ATTRIBUTE('default_timezone', val)`, `DBMS_SCHEDULER.GET_ATTRIBUTE(job_name, 'follow_default_timezone', bool)` and `START_DATE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`log_date` is always in system timezone
`actual_start_date` is taking the timezone from`start date` if not exist it is taken from scheduler's parameter `default_timezone`

```
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name             => 'Test',
   job_type             => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
   job_action           => 'BEGIN null; END;',
   enabled              =>  TRUE, 
   comments             => 'xxx');
END;
/

BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name             => 'Test',
   job_type             => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
   job_action           => 'BEGIN null; END;',
   start_date           =>  current_timestamp, -- tz from session
   enabled              =>  TRUE,
   comments             => 'xxx');
END;
/

select * from user_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS
```